# Visualforce with Map in Map to get rate of login between current and last week

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

I'm trying to program a VF page to get the list of org's users and their logins this week versus last week, but I'm not able to deal with this "Map/Map" thing to do so.

Can anyone help me deal with this?

Here is the part of the controller:

```
public class monitorController {
    //comparación de dos semanas
    public Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> getUsHisC(){
        String mapeo='';
        Map<Integer, Integer> numeros = new Map<Integer, Integer>();
        Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> UsHistC = new Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();
        for(User usuariosC : [SELECT Username, Id FROM User]){
            mapeo = usuariosC.Username;
            System.debug('User Id = '+usuariosC.Id);
            Integer numLoginsC1 = [SELECT count() FROM LoginHistory WHERE LoginTime = THIS_WEEK AND UserId = :usuariosC.Id];            
            String nombreUsuarioC1 = usuariosC.Username;
            System.debug('NumLogins esta semana = '+numLoginsC1);
            Integer numLoginsC2 = [SELECT count() FROM LoginHistory WHERE LoginTime = LAST_WEEK AND UserId = :usuariosC.Id];            
            System.debug('NumLogins semana pasada = '+numLoginsC2);
            numeros.put(numLoginsC1, numLoginsC2);
            UsHistC.put(nombreUsuarioC1, numeros);
            System.debug('UsHist dice '+UsHistC);
            mapeo += ','+numLoginsC1+','+numLoginsC2;
            Set<String> users = new Set<String>();
            users = UsHistC.keySet();
        }
        return UsHistC;
    }
}
```

And here is the code in the VF page (I tried `apex:repeat` and other bad guesses):

```
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!usHisC}" var="loggedA">
            <apex:variable var="A" value="{!loggedA}" />
            <apex:variable var="B" value="{!usHisC[A]}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Nombre de usuario" value="{!loggedA}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Esta semana" value="{!usHisC[loggedA]}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Semana pasada" value="{!B}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Never use queries inside a loop. You can do all of this in a single pass with an aggregate result query:

```
AggregateResult[] results = [
    SELECT DAY_ONLY(LoginTime) dayOfMonth, UserId loginUserId, COUNT(ID) loginCount
    FROM LoginHistory
    WHERE LoginTime = THIS_WEEK OR LoginTime = LAST_WEEK
    GROUP BY DAY_ONLY(LoginTime), UserId
];
```

From there, you just need to sort out the results based on the day of the month and the user Id.

Comment: thank you, but what I want is to get the count of logins this week and the count of logins the previous week (it's like a 3-col table: user-id, count this wk, count last wk)... can I get that result from this query?

Comment: @BernardoLira Yes (sort of). The query itself doesn't have the data directly, but you can derive the data from this query. That's why I suggested it.

Comment: I was unable to create a 3-column "cursor" (table) with this SOQL sentence after all... I'm still stuck. Sorry and thank you for your help...